# How to convert python Unicode string to bytes

Tags: python, string, unicode

I have a string `x` as below

```
x = "\xe9\x94\x99\xe8\xaf\xaf"
```

This string should be Unicode string, but cannot be displayed (print) correctly.

And the string `y` is Unicode string/ bytes started with `b`, And `y` can be displayed correctly by `y.decode('utf-8')`

```
y = b"\xe9\x94\x99\xe8\xaf\xaf"
```

My question is how to convert x to y ?

Comment: How are those supposed to be displayed? My Windows sees `"é[x][x]è"` for `x`, and `"[x][x]"` for `y`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming we're talking about Python3, the Unicode string `x` is 6 code points long. It happens to be that each of those code points is in range `0x00` to `0xff` (ASCII subset). We can get the exact byte string with the [`raw_unicode_escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings) codec, like this:

```
>>> x = "\xe9\x94\x99\xe8\xaf\xaf"
>>> y = x.encode('raw_unicode_escape')
>>> y
b'\xe9\x94\x99\xe8\xaf\xaf'
>>> y.decode('utf8')
'错误'
```

Note that this will only work if the string `x` contains only ASCII subrange of Unicode; otherwise you'll just get escaped Unicode code points (as the codec's name suggests):

```
>>> "šž".encode('raw_unicode_escape')
b'\\u0161\\u017e'
```